# MySQL find ids for which there is no existing row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables :

```
1. Person (person_id, name) : (1, "Test1"), (2, "Test2"), (3, "Test3")
2. Role (role_id, description) : (1, "Admin"), (2, "Designer"), (3, "Developer") ..
3. PersonRoles (person_id, role_id) : (1 , 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)
```

Is it possible in MySQL with a query to get the ids of the people for which there`s no row with exact role in the PersonRoles table. For Example if I want to check for "Designer" role the query should return ids: 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
select person_id from Person
                where person_id not in 
               (select person_id from Role r 
                   inner join PersonRoles pr on pr.role_id=r.role_id
                where r.description='Designer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Person p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Role r
                   JOIN   PersonRoles pr ON r.role_id = pr.role_id
                   WHERE  r.description = 'Designer' AND
                          pr.person_id = p.person_id)
```